Understanding MUBUF instruction in AMD GCN Architecture
I am trying to understand how MUBUF instruction works using the following kernel. Assume only 1 wavefront (64 WIs).

According to ISA ref guide gcn3-instruction-set-architecture.pdf,
ADDR = Base + baseOffset + Ioffset + Voffset + Stride * (Vindex + TID)

I set the stride to 64B (in s7 reg) in hopes that each thread will load data from different cache line. The first buffer_load will load 64 values into L1 and L2, but the second buffer_load should skip L1 and fetch from L2 since GLC is enabled.
I expected there to be 64 L2 hits. However I observe only 1 L2 hit. Why is that? What is happening here? Coalescing? and what can I do to achieve 64 hits for 64 work items?
I know this is a bit of an odd question but indulge me. (GFX8 ISA)
    //; Define buffer resource descriptor in scalar registers s4, s5, s6, s7
    //; For simplicity, we'll set up a basic resource descriptor assuming a linear buffer starting at address 0
    __asm volatile("s_mov_b32 s4, 0x0 ");// Base address low 32-bits
    __asm volatile("s_mov_b32 s5, 0x0 ");// Base address high 32-bits (upper 32 bits of 64-bit address)
    __asm volatile("s_mov_b32 s6, 0xffffffff ");// Size (set to max for simplicity)
    __asm volatile("s_mov_b32 s7, 0x00027001 ");// Stride and other buffer resource descriptor fields, ADD_TID_ENABLE = 1 and stride 64 Bytes
    
    //(assuming normal settings here, specific details depend on actual requirements)
    //Set up the offset in s1, which will be 4096 in this example
    __asm volatile("s_mov_b32 s1, 4096");// Offset value
    
    //Format: buffer_load_dword vdata, voffset, srsrc, soffset [idxen] [glc] [slc] [tfe] [lds]
    __asm volatile("buffer_load_dword v1, off, s[4:7], s1 "); //Load dword from address (base + 4096) with GLC disabled
    __asm volatile("buffer_load_dword v1, off, s[4:7], s1 glc"); //Load dword from address (base + 4096) with GLC enabled

